# $R$ projection operator in entanglement entropy

Tags: condensed-matter, entropy, conformal-field-theory, topological-insulators, lattice-model

I was reading a paper about entanglement entropy. The author introduced a real space cutoff operator $R$ which he claimed to project onto a real space subregion. Then he used $\bar P:=RPR$ as an operator he concerned, where $P$ was the projection onto the occupied band.

My question is, is there a matrix representation of this $R$ for lattice models?

source:[link](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.09505)

Comment: Source/reference?...

Comment: @JasonFunderberker [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.09505)